# Conditional reboot in innosetup installer

Tags: inno-setup

I have an innosetup installer that downloads and installs the .net 4.6.1 framework if it is needed. However I need to prompt to reboot at the end of installation (after installing .Net AND my application) only if this occurred.

How do I do ask the user to reboot in innosetup if a boolean is true?

Comment: So I read the IS documentation about NeedsRestart() but I don't quite understand how it's used. Do I simply implement it returning True, and just call it from my installer?

Comment: No. It's an event function. You do not call it. Inno Setup calls it to ask (you) if the restart is needed. So you implement it to return true, when you want restart (= when you have installed the framework). Exactly as shown in the linked/duplicate question.

Comment: Another option can be seen if you look at the `CodePrepareToInstall` example script.  It uses some advanced concepts but it shows how to install a prerequisite, reboot, and *then* continue your application install.  (Which is slightly different than what you're asking for, but perhaps will suit.)  A much easier option is to set `RestartIfNeededByRun=true` and run the .NET installer from the `[Run]` section.  This relies on Inno's internal detection of whether the installer did something that requires a reboot (but you can use `NeedsRestart` to override that if you really need to).